# Log corresponding response to message?

Tags: jquery

In the following code, I wish to have the function message log in the console the corresponding response to messages, and if it is not in the array messages to log "I didn't quite catch that"

What I mean is like

message("Hi") would log "Hello" because both have the index of 2

Here is my code, I know it is way off, but thanks

```
function message(text) {
                messages = ['Hello', 'hello', 'Hi', 'hi'];
                responses = ['Hi', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Hello'];
                msgKnown = jQuery.inArray(text, arr);
                if (!msgKnown) {
                    console.log("I didn't quite catch that");
                }
                else {
                    console.log(msgKnown);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't that way off. And they would have an index of 2 since that would make it the 3rd one (remember it starts at 0..)

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GGvz2/) thanks to @badAdviceGuy

I think this is what you're looking for..

```
function message(text) {
    messages = ['Hello', 'hello', 'Hi', 'hi'];
    responses = ['Hi', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Hello'];
    msgKnown = jQuery.inArray(text, messages); // <----- I modified this
    if (!msgKnown) {
        console.log("I didn't quite catch that");
    }
    else {
        console.log(responses[msgKnown]); // <---- I modified this
    }
}

message("Hi"); // will output "Hello"
```

Comment: Beat me to it, here is the fiddle showcasing this solution working [http://jsfiddle.net/GGvz2/](http://jsfiddle.net/GGvz2/). @Sam, you were calling on array `arr` instead of `messages`.

Comment: Thanks @badAdviceGuy I'll add your jsfiddle to my answer.

Comment: Works, except it says undefined rather than I didn't quite catch that

Comment: How do I stop it from logging undefined?

Comment: @Sam where does it log that?

Comment: If I type in a string not in the array, such as "123". Also if I type Hello it says "I didn't quite catch that"

Comment: for the case of entering `"123"` in `jQuery.inArray(text, messages);` returns -1 if it doesn't find it. and `(!msgKnown)` is not true so it tried to return the value at the array index -1 which is undefined. for the case of entering `"Hello"` it returns 0 because its the first one. 0 could also be interpreted as false so `(!0)` is true and returns `"I didn't quite catch that"`

Comment: @Sam change `(!msgKnown)` to `(msgKnown == -1)`.